# gems executable-hook is not found when trying to build ios flutter project

Tags: ios, ruby, flutter, rubygems

when I run the flutter run command I face this error from gems files

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
           ↳
[        ]     Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
               Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
```

and actually tried running this  `gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1` as the error suggested but ends up with this error

```
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/[user_name]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/plugins/executable-hooks_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- executable-hooks/wrapper (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you run flutter clean, pub get and try running pod update. and thank me later if it works